# Continue after SIGNAL with a python script in gdb

Tags: python, gdb

I am trying to generate some output on segmentation faults (and other signals) with a python script in gdb. The script looks like this:

```
import gdb

def event_handler(event):
    gdb.execute("set scheduler-locking on") # this is needed to avoid parallel exec of the handler

    gdb.write("\n[ME] SIG " + event.stop_signal)
    frame = gdb.selected_frame()
    while frame:
        gdb.write("\n[ME] FN " + str(frame.name()))
        frame = frame.older()

# make sure output goes to a file
gdb.execute("set logging on") 
gdb.execute("set logging file gdbout")
gdb.events.stop.connect(event_handler)
```

The problem is that I need to press c and Enter on every segmentation fault, the script does not continue.

If I do

```
gdb.execute("continue")
```

in the handler, I get a StackOverflow. I think this is because execute() never returns. If I do

```
handle SIGSEGV nostop
```

My handler is not invoked any longer. How can I continue after the handler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I found out how to do it:

First, I need a callable for the continue command. As suggested by Tom, this will be used with post_event:

```
class Executor:
    def __init__(self, cmd):
        self.__cmd = cmd

    def __call__(self):
        gdb.execute(self.__cmd)
```

And here is the event handler:

```
def event_handler(event):
    gdb.execute("set scheduler-locking on") # to avoid parallel signals in other threads

    gdb.write("\n[ME] SIG " + event.stop_signal)
    frame = gdb.selected_frame()
    while frame:
        gdb.write("\n[ME] FN " + str(frame.name()))
        frame = frame.older()
    gdb.execute("set scheduler-locking off") # otherwise just this thread is continued, leading to a deadlock   
    gdb.post_event(Executor("continue")) # and post the continue command to gdb
```

And then, to invoke it:

```
gdb.execute("set logging on")
gdb.execute("set logging file gdbout")
gdb.execute("set pagination off")
gdb.events.stop.connect(event_handler)
```

The trick is to disable scheduler-locking later, it is needed to avoid concurrency problems, but it leads to a deadlock if no handler is running.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for you, there still isn't a good Python API to signals in gdb.  Instead you have to resort to hacks.  That said, your approach seems pretty good to me.

To deal with the "continue" issue, I'd suggest using `gdb.post_event` to insert an event into gdb's event queue.  The event can invoke the `continue` command.  This should avoid the stack overflow problem at least.

Comment: Unfortunately the entire debugger gets stuck with this solution.